# Code in nested If statement not printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem and it is that my code isn't displaying after the nested statement.

After `confirmation.lower == no`, it asks the Wrong Info Input and then skips to the Else statement without executing what is in any of the if or elif statements.

```
confirmation = input("Confirm if information is correct ('yes' or 'no'):")

#confirms if deatils are incorrect
if confirmation.lower() == "no":
    wronginfo = input("Indicate Wrong Info:")
    if wronginfo.lower() == "First Name":

        NewInfo = input(wronginfo+":")
        FirstName = NewInfo
        details()


    elif wronginfo.lower() == "Last Name":

        NewInfo = input(wronginfo+":")
        LastName = NewInfo
        details()


    elif wronginfo.lower() == "Age":
        NewInfo = input(wronginfo+":")
        Age = NewInfo
        details()


   else:
    start = input("Type 'y' to start:")
```

Note: Details is a function that prints All info such as First Name and last name

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have `wronginfo.lower() == "Last Name":` which contains upper case letters and will never be True.

Your options are. Change `Last Name` to `last name`

```
wronginfo.lower() == "last name"
```

If you would like to keep `Last Name` then you can use `.title()`. This will make the first letter of each word a capital and every other letter lower case, which matches what you're trying to compare.

```
wronginfo.title() == "Last Name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare string with all characters in lower case to strings that consist upper case letters

Answer (score 1):

This statement can never come up true:

```
elif wronginfo.lower() == "Last Name":
```

Your comparison string has upper-case characters; there is no lower-case string that can equal it.  Perhaps try this:

```
elif wronginfo.lower() == "last name":
```

You will need the same treatment with "First Name" and "Age".

Now, if you like the way your current code reads, simply convert both to lower case like so:

```
elif wronginfo.lower() == "Last Name".lower():
```

You get the capitals for program maintenance at the cost of a small amount of CPU time.  Since you're working at human typing speeds, that time is not likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

wronginfo.lower() will never equal "First Name" because "First Name" has capital letters in it. Change to

```
if wronginfo.lower() == "first name":
```